# How to stop Listbox from growing on screen as new items are inserted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

My WPF application has a window that contains a `ListBox`.  For some reason that I don't understand, it started growing on screen today after items are inserted into it.  I want its height to stay fixed and I don't want it to grow every time an item is inserted.

Here's the XAML for the window:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}"
          Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource AlarmTitleBackground}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              MouseLeftButtonDown="LeftMouseButtonDown">
            . . .
        </Grid>

        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource AlarmTitleBackground}"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Height="4" />

        <Grid Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackground}"
              Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Name="PendingAlarmScope">
                <ListBox Background="{DynamicResource TextBackground}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                         Margin="5"
                         MinWidth="185"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Name="AlarmsList"
                         SelectionChanged="AlarmsList_SelectionChanged" />
            </Grid>
            . . .
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

I found a post in a blog about a `TextBox` that kept growing as characters were typed.  The author indicated that the `TextBox` was in a `ScrollViewer` with the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property set to "Auto".  They changed it to "Disabled" and this fixed it for them.  I tried adding `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisiblility="Disabled" to the xaml but this didn't work.  I also tried binding the`ListBox's MaxHeight `property to the`ActualHeight` of another control that's the same exact height as I want & that didn't work, either.

How do I fix the `Height` of the `ListBox` without setting it?  I want the `ListBox` to always fill the `Grid` cell it's in, and the window to grow and rescale itself for different screen resolutions.

Comment: can you try to use the hack provided here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386039/wpf-textbox-and-scroll-behavior

Comment: That didn't work, but I believe it's because of the `ViewBox`.  See my comment to Blam's answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a ListView from expanding the window dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694883/how-to-prevent-a-listview-from-expanding-the-window-dimension)

Comment: @MikeNakis: Thanks very much for that and it probably would fix the problem. Unfortunately, I've been out of that job since 2016 and the question is no longer relevant to me. However, it will be good to know if I'm ever in that situation again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of trying numerous things, I finally bit the bullet & set the `Height` of the `ListBox` to a value that I found using Snoop before it started growing.  This stopped it from growing every time a new item was inserted.  It was the only thing I could find to do that worked.  A very frustrating day.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a ListBox inside of Grids and DockPanels (there was no explicit ViewBox).  The listbox was initially being sized to fit with other controls (as expected) but would grow when items were added (undesired) even when `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` were both set on the ListBox :(  We also ended up being frustrated and having to hardcode the height.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackground}"
              Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

for grins would you try dropping the view box and some other stuff

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}"
          Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource AlarmTitleBackground}"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Height="4" />


                <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Background="{DynamicResource TextBackground}"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                         Margin="5"
                         MinWidth="185"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Name="AlarmsList"
                         SelectionChanged="AlarmsList_SelectionChanged" />

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.  No change in behavior.

Comment: I dropped the `ViewBox` only and the `ListBox` stopped growing.  However, the `ViewBox` is needed to make the control look right at different resolutions.  I understand why the `ListBox` is growing when it's in the `ViewBox` -- the `ViewBox` makes it think it has infinite room.  I need to get the effect on the layout without the `ListBox` growing as things are inserted into it.

Comment: So the problem is the ViewBox and not even worth a +1.  Did you try ViewBox(es) in the Grid?

Comment: Dude, no need to get snippy.  I gave you a +1.  I'm still trying to figure this out & sorry if I didn't do it fast enough for you.